# Generate uniform random number in open interval

Tags: c++, random

I cannot find a way to generate random number from uniform distribution in an open interval like (0,1).

```
(double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
```

will this include 0 and 1? If yes, what is the correct way to generate random number in an open interval?

Comment: std::rand() gives you an int, and it will be zero with 1/RAND_MAX possibility. Furthermore, it isn't uniform distribution, it is a discrete distribution with RAND_MAX number of possible values distributed equally in [0,1].

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [std::uniform_real_distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_real_distribution/)! You can use a more professional pseudo random number generator than the bulit-in of `<cstdlib>` called std::rand(). Here's a code example that print outs 10 random numbers in range [0,1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{  
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        std::cout << distribution(generator) << endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

It is very unlikely to get exactly zero. If it is very important for you to not to get 0, you can check for it and generate another number.

And of course you can use random number engine specified, as `std::mt19937`(that is "very" random) or one of the fastest, the `std::knuth_b`.

Comment: "It is very unlikely to get exactly zero" --> 50000 throws and you'll be sure to have it ...

Comment: The chance you get exactly zero is smaller than 1e-16. The probability you get zero is 1 / {number of doubles between [0,1)} .

Comment: I know what the theoretical probability is. I am saying that if you use a bad PRNG you can have 0 every 50000 throws with the `cmath` PRNG. And it's the real life probability that counts, not the theoretical one. :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't written C++ in ages but try the following code:

```
double M = 0.00001, N = 0.99999;
double rNumber = M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't programmed in C++ for a number of years now, but when I did the implementation of rand was compiler specific.  Implementations varied as to whether they covered [0,RAND_MAX], [0,RAND_MAX), (0,RAND_MAX], or (0,RAND_MAX).  That may have changed, and I'm sure somebody will chime in if it has.

Assume that the implementation is over the closed interval [0,RAND_MAX], then `(double)(rand()+1)/(RAND_MAX+2);` should yield an open interval U(0,1) unless `RAND_MAX` is pushing up against the word size, in which case cast to long. Adjust the additive constants if your generator covers the range differently.

An even better solution would be to ditch `rand` and use something like the Mersenne Twister from the Boost libraries.  MT has different calls which explicitly give you control over the open/closed range of the results.

Comment: Due to numerical instabilities `x / (RAND_MAX + 2)` is no longer uniform. Given the forum, I still think it's good enough.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Why is covering the range [1,RAND_MAX] in steps of size 1/(RAND_MAX+2) to get results in (0,1) less numerically stable than covering the range [0,RAND_MAX] in steps of size 1/RAND_MAX to get results in [0,1]? Neither is using all the mantissa bits of a double.

Comment: The trick is that 1/RAND_MAX when RAND_MAX is a power of two, uses all the 31 bits in the double with uniform distribution. Dividing by 2^31 + 2 or so, will accumulate rounding errors towards some bit-patterns.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I could see that if we were casting to float, but the mantissa of a double is 53 bits - way more than the precision of RAND_MAX. And I know that several LCG algorithms use modulus's which aren't powers of two, and convert to U(0,1) by scaling by the modulus, so color me skeptical. Do you have a cite, I'd love to learn more if you are correct.

Comment: In doubles with 52 bits of mantissa and 31 bits of precision, the majority of doubles aren't used. But those, that are, have exactly the same likelihood and are equally spaced apart; Since 2^52 is not divisible by (2^31 + 2), either the spacing of individual elements must have jitter, or by the pigeonhole principle, must locate to same slots. It's no excuse, that there exists non-perfect algorithms and as stated, they are probably good enough for many applications.

Answer (score 0):

Given uniform distribution of a RNG with closed interval [a, b], the easiest method is to simply discard unwanted values an throw the dice again. This is both numerically stable and practically the fastest method to maintain uniformity.

```
 double myRnD()
 {
    double a = 0.0;
    while (a == 0.0 || a == 1.0) a = (double)rand() * (1.0 / (double)RAND_MAX);
    return a;
 }
```

(Disclaimer: RAND_MAX would have to be a power of two and < 2^52)