# Avoid division by zero in C when taking log with respect to a random number

Tags: c, random, gaussian, divide-by-zero

I am currently using C to generate a Gaussian noise. In one step, I need to take the log of a uniformly distributed number `u1 = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX`. Because `u1` may be zero, there is a risk in doing `log(u1)`. So, I need to check. Should I use

```
do {
    u1 = ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX);
} while (u1 == 0.);
```

Or, should I use

```
do {
    u1 = ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX);
} while (u1 < epsilon);
```

where `epsilon` is a small number? If the latter is preferred, how should I choose the value of epsilon? (In Fortran there is `TINY`, but I do not know what to do in C).

Attached is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double gaussian_noise(double mean, double std)
{
    static int have_spare = 0;
    static double u1, u2, z1, z2;
    if(have_spare)
    {
        have_spare = 0;
        z2 = sqrt(-2. * log(u1)) * sin(2. * M_PI * u2);
        return mean + std * z2;
    }
    have_spare = 1;
    do {
    u1 = ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX);
    } while (u1 == 0.);
    u2 = ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX);
    z1 = sqrt(-2. * log(u1)) * cos(2. * M_PI * u2);
    return mean + std * z1;
}

void main()
{
    const double mean = 0., std = 1.;
    double noise;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<100000; i++)
    {
        noise = gaussian_noise(mean, std);
        printf("%lf\t", noise);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just checking it against 0 suffices. Log of the smallest value (Double.MIN_VALUE) produces well defined number.

Comment: should work as it is. Wrt TINY in Fortran, there is header <float.h> in C with a lots of relevant constants, please check it

Comment: `1.0/RAND_MAX` is still nearly 600 times larger than the smallest positive double value if `RAND_MAX == INT_MAX` so you don't need to worry

Comment: You can skip the loop by using `(rand() + 1.0) / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)`.  Note carefully that for most C libraries, `rand()` is a _terrible_ random number generator.  If you're using the result for any serious application, get a better one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make sure that the result of `rand()` isn't 0 so that you won't have to do the conversion to double and division again and again

```
int r = rand();
while (r == 0)
    r = rand();

u1 = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
```

An even simpler solution is

```
u1 = (double)(rand() + 1U)/(RAND_MAX + 1U);
```

This way you don't need the loop anymore

However you should generate 53 bits for the double mantissa to get more proper precision and distribution instead of (typically) only 15 or 31 bits with `rand()`. A sample solution is Java [`Random().nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29)

```java
public double nextDouble() {
    return (((long)next(26) << 27) + next(27))
         / (double)(1L << 53);
}
```

> [In early versions of Java, the result was incorrectly calculated as:
>
> ```
> return (((long)next(27) << 27) + next(27))
>     / (double)(1L << 54);
> ```
>
> This might seem to be equivalent, if not better, but in fact it introduced a large nonuniformity because of the bias in the rounding of floating-point numbers: it was three times as likely that the low-order bit of the significand would be 0 than that it would be 1! This nonuniformity probably doesn't matter much in practice, but we strive for perfection.]

Comment: Thank you all so much for the help! These are all really great answers, but I only get to pick one. So I picked this, because for Box Muller it is (0, 1]. But still thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 4):

As nhahtdh says, zero is the only problem number, so it's the only one to throw out.  Comparing floating point numbers with `==` and `!=` is usually not preferable.  In this case, however, it's exactly what you want: anything that isn't exactly the floating point `(double)(0.)` passes.

Comment: Thank you! Good answer. Sorry that I only get to pick one.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by @nhahtdh, OP's current code is sufficient.

Yet I suspect an "off by 1 error".

OP's code will generate the range: 0.0 (exclusive) to 1.0 (inclusive).  Yet for this task I would expect a 0.0 (inclusive) to 1.0 (exclusive) with the 0.0 removed.

Should code want the range 0.0 (exclusive) to 1.0 (exclusive) consider

```
u1 = ((double) rand() + 0.5) / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
```

Comment: in case of open range, the answer was posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933419/generate-uniform-random-number-in-open-interval). `(double)(rand() + 1U)/(RAND_MAX + 2U)` might work the same, and it's better in case double addition is worse than integer addition on that architecture

Comment: Great answer and insight! Sorry that I only get to pick one. Hopefully an upvote would do a little bit too :)